# Simplifying complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to ask whether my thoughts are right.

> If $z_1=(\frac1{\sqrt2+\mathbb i\sqrt2})^{100}$ Simplifying $z_1$.

After computing out the angle of $π/4$ and the $r=|z_1|$ I got this:

$$z_{1} =(\frac12)^{100} e^{\pi i}$$

Did I make any faults?
Could it be simplified any further?

Comment: Id have to check whether its even right, but if it is, $e^{i\pi}$ is equal to -1 which means you could simplify further to $-0.5^{100}$

Comment: You are right. All right, then it would be: z_{1} = -0,5^{100}.

Comment: Yes, although you can simplify $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're answer is correct, although you can simplify a tiny bit more :

$$\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{2}i}\right)^{100} = \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}- \sqrt{2}i}{\|\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{2}i\|^2}\right)^{100} \\= \left(\frac{(\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2)^2}e^{i\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}{(\sqrt{2})^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2}\right)^{100} \\= \left(\frac{2e^{i\tan(1)}}{4}\right)^{100} \\= \left( \frac{1}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)^{100}\\ = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}e^{i\frac{100\pi}{4}}\\ = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}e^{i25\pi}\\ =\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}e^{i\pi}\\ = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}\cdot(-1)$$